# Error while mail trigger

Tags: java, email, smtp

I have the program for mail trigger. I have access rights for mail trigger from my machine to SMTP server. Even I am able to telnet and ping to 10.242.175.70/25 . But when I am running my program on my machine I am facing error as below. Please help me to resolve this and also let me know where I am doing wrong. I have provided the activatio.jar and mail.jar, if I am missing any other jar then let me know that too.

[image]

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import javax.activation.*;

public class SendEmail
{
   public static void main(String [] args)
   {    
      // Recipient's email ID needs to be mentioned.
      String to = "mohit.darmwal@cognizant.com";

      // Sender's email ID needs to be mentioned
      String from = "mohit.darmwal@cognizant.com";

      // Assuming you are sending email from localhost
      String host = " 10.243.33.234";//"localhost";//"192.168.195.68";

      // Get system properties
      Properties properties = System.getProperties();

      // Setup mail server
      properties.setProperty("10.242.175.70", host);

      // Get the default Session object.
      Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

      try{
         // Create a default MimeMessage object.
         MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

         // Set From: header field of the header.
         message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

         // Set To: header field of the header.
         message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                                  new InternetAddress(to));

         // Set Subject: header field
         message.setSubject("This is the Subject Line!");

         // Now set the actual message
         message.setText("This is actual message");

         // Send message
         Transport.send(message);
         System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");
      }catch (MessagingException mex) {
         mex.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Checkout [JavaMail API](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/) for reference which properties to set and how to fill them.

The specific error in this case was setting the hostname wrong:

```
  // Setup mail server
  //Does not work this way:
  //properties.setProperty("10.242.175.70", host);           
  //Use correct property name
  properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", "10.242.175.70");
```